# Как рассчитываются задержки в функции Delay_ms при программировании на ATmega32?

Tags: c, avr-gcc, atmel-studio, avr

Добрый день!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, уже пару часов ломаю голову...
В microC есть функция Delay_ms. Например, Delay_ms(11). Она устанавливает задержку на 11 миллисекунд.
Тактовая частота - 8 МГц.
В ассемблере эта инструкция выглядит так:

```
;Delay_ms(11);
        LDI        R17, 115
        LDI        R16, 72
L_main8:
        DEC        R16
        BRNE       L_main8
        DEC        R17
        BRNE       L_main8
```

DEC выполняется 1 такт, BRNE - 1 такт, если нет перехода, 2 такта, если есть.
Теперь если посчитать количество тактов, то можно узнать время (11 миллисекунд).
Я пытаюсь посчитать количество тактов так:

```
((1+2)*71 + 2) * 115 * (1+2) + 1 = 74 176
```

Теперь, чтобы узнать время задержки, надо разделить на частоту:

```
74 176 / 8*10^6  = 0,009272 = 9 мс
```

Итого, вместо 11 миллисекунд я получаю 9. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем я наврала? Предполагаю, что ошибка в подсчете количества тактов, но не вижу ее.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Хм. Насколько я понимаю, внутренний цикл имеет длину в 72 итерации только на первой итерации внешнего цикла, правильно? Все остальные итерации прогоняют от максимального значения `R16`.

**Обновление**

Подождите, ещё ж надо учесть остальные внутренние циклы! В точке `L_main8` у нас получаются такие значения R16 и R17:

```
 72  115
 71  115
   ...
  1  115 (проход во внешний цикл)
  0  114
255  114 (или что получается из 0 после DEC?)
254  114
  ...
  1  114
  0  113
```

и т. д.

Comment: @VladD, спасибо за ответ! Тогда получается 72*3 + 115* 5  = 791..? вообще очень маленькое число получается...

Comment: @IceFox: Подождите, ещё ж надо учесть остальные внутренние циклы! В точке `L_main8` у нас получаются такие значения R16 и R17:

    72  115
    71  115
      ...
     1  115 (проход во внешний цикл)
     0  114
   255  114 (или что получается из 0 после DEC?)
   254  114
     ...
     1  114
     0  113

и т. д.

Answer (score 0):

```
;Delay_ms(11);
    LDI        R17, 115  // 1 такт
    LDI        R16, 72   // 1 такт
L_main8:
    DEC        R16       // цикл 1 - 1 такт
    BRNE       L_main8   // цикл 1 - 2 такта
    DEC        R17       // цикл 2 - 1 такт
    BRNE       L_main8   // цикл 2 - 2 такта.
```

Давайте посчитаем:
наружный цикл выполнится 115 раз. На каждом цикле будет одно вычитание и один переход - итого 3 такта (последняя итерация 2 такта) итого 3 * 115 - 1 = 344 такта. 
Внутренний цикл первый раз пройдёт 72 итерации 3 * 72 - 1 = 215
и остальные 114 раз пройдёт 256 итераций (3 * 256 - 1) * 114 = 87 438
прибавим 2 такта на LDI получается
2 + 344 + 215 + 87438 = 87999 = без одного такта 88000 циклов, т.е. 11 мс при 8МГц